# Why am I getting down votes on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I do my best to follow the rules for asking question on Stack Overflow and I need a little guidance on this one:

[Deep understanding: Why do .bind(this) not seem to follow the normal rules when used with new Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603172/deep-understanding-why-do-bindthis-not-seem-to-follow-the-normal-rules-when?noredirect=1#comment66515149_39603172)

Why I am I getting down votes on it - I feel like I am being punished for asking a question that some people with more expertise than me find "stupid"? Please help me understand.

Comment: Some people may think that this is a "no duh" moment with JavaScript, although I really don't see anything wrong with asking for clarification.  I wouldn't read much into it.

Comment: function.bind, this, and all are very well documented all over the web. It's certainly plausible that they simply don't think you did enough research before asking.

Comment: First of all, don't take downvotes personally. Often questions that ask "why does this work?" or "What makes this code work?" are downvoted, even though they are on-topic for SO. Secondly, the downvotes here probably correlate to the "not useful" part of the tooltip on downvote button, as the code works. It could also be due to "does not show any research effort" for the reasons @KevinB illustrated in his comment.

Comment: It seems your code contains syntax-errors, at least if I run it in a code-snippet, it barks at me.

Comment: Thank you - it helped. I guess it can sometimes be difficult for beginners to convince experienced people that sufficient research was done prior to asking (I actually spent many hours on my own investigating) and to ask question perceived as useful to the broader community. No excuse for the syntax-errors - that was sloppy (and has been corrected).

Comment: Also, you should fix the bad indentation, as this gives the impression you didn't really bother to format your question properly, which further decreases the perceived effort you may have put into the question.

Comment: Thank you @LucasTrzesniewski . It has been done

Comment: @rabbitco Please also carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - trying to remove unrelated parts of code either brings solution or at least allow you to show minimal code (possibly with second piece of code later showing real usage if minimal sample looks awkward).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't see what parts of this code are unrelated.

Comment: @torazaburo OP seem to have problems with when value actually evaluated for call parameters - there is likely simple version of the code. I.e. whole inner func + bind is not really needed, also it is not specific to promise nor ES6... Experimenting with code could have helped OP to narrow down misunderstanding (but potentially avoid asking questions on SO and META which decreases something :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this post does not satisfy the criteria for downvoting.

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

I've seen this a thousand times, but now that I look at it again I can't tell it exactly what it means. The natural interpretation would be

> This question (does not show any research effort) AND (is unclear OR not useful)

Or does the semi-colon mean something different from AND? Wikipedia informs us that the semi-colon may be used as a kind of comma, but that does not seem to be the case here. Or that it may be used between clauses which are "balanced, opposed or contradictory". "Balanced" would imply AND; "opposed or contradictory" again does not seem to be applicable here. Or does it mean "This question does not show any research effort AND POSSIBLY AS A RESULT IS unclear or not useful", imputing a kind of causal effect to the semi-colon?

So is not showing any research effort a requirement? Or is merely being unclear or not useful enough? If merely not being clear justifies a downvote, how is that different from the "Unclear what you are asking" reason for closing? Is a distinction being made between the entire post being unclear, and the post missing a clear question?

Anyway, whatever this question may be, it is not unclear, so let's get that out of the way. What about "not useful"? Sometimes this can be applied to questions involving code that works, where the OP is asking how to improve it. Then it's a question for code review or something, which could be indicated in a comment. But in this case the OP is not asking how to improve it; he's asking how it works, or rather WHY it works. That seems like a valid question.

Or is it "not useful" because `this` has already been described to death? Entire chapters of books have been devoted to it. SO has its own (very long) [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Yet we should not be surprised that `this` continues to confuse and surprise people who are starting down their JS learning curve. Seeking resolution to such confusion does not seem "not useful". In this case, we have factors involved not normally seen in `this` questions, including the presence of the promise constructor, which itself uses the semi-non-intuitive "revealing constructor" pattern (who came up with that name? what is being "revealed"?).

Moving on to whether or not this question "does not show any research effort", this is a matter of opinion and guesswork. If you define "research effort" as googling for "this promise bind" or whatever, the OP could well have done this, and still have been confused. Or do we define research as meaning having read (and successfully digested) all available materials on a topic? This is not a case where he could google an API and be told "omitting the second parameter will crash your computer".

In terms of the five downvotes, it's fair to attribute two of them to the same people that voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". Those closevotes are puzzling in my opinion, most likely based on not reading through the question. This may be an example of the undesirable (in my mind) yet all-too-common phenomenon I see of "simultaneously downvote AND closevote anything you sort of don't like". Of the other three downvotes, perhaps one or more were caused by the post being poorly formatted and missing some parentheses. I hate poorly-formatted posts as much as the next guy, and admit to having downvoted some questions solely for that reason, but the formatting problems here were not that serious and did not impede the understanding of the question; a comment pointing out the problems would have been entirely sufficient. The remaining downvotes were either drive-bys, or possibly could have been based on the notion that actually nothing out of the ordinary was happening and that normal rules for `this` could be applied in a straightforward way to understand the behavior, which I can understand, but the whole point is that in this question the OP did not fully understand the normal rules or how to apply them.

In my opinion, this question merits neither downvotes nor closevotes.

Comment: IMO you should read it as an AND, a question can be good and valuable without shown research effort. In any case, I think it is difficult for people to not vote at all, they have to either upvote or otherwise downvote.